# Estimating PDF of ratio of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, estimation, sampling

I have a step in my project in which I have two random variables $U$ and $V$ with their distributions, and I need to calculate the quantity $\frac{U}{U+V}$. Unfortunately, this ratio does not have an analitically tractable distribution.

My question is: is it possible to compute the PDF of the ratio by taking samples from the numerator, taking samples from the denominator, computing the ratio and then using the histogram of the ratios as the estimate for the PDF?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not take samples of the ratio directly?

Comment: Nameless: how can I do that? I don't have the distribution of the ratio. That's what I'm trying to estimate. Apologize if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Your proposal matches the concept of an empirical function distribution. Be careful if it's possible for $U+V \approx 0$, because in this case it's possible for a small (rarely sampled) part of the distribution to make a large contribution to the expectation of the ratio.

Comment: I think @Nameless was suggesting simulating or sampling  $U$ and $V$ than then looking at the empirical distribution of $\frac{U}{U+V}$

Comment: Ah, I understand now. @Henry, does this method also work if U and V are not independent?

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are dependent, then presumably you want to sample them together in a way that reflects the dependence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Graphical comment:* Using R.

```
u = runif(10^6); v = runif(10^6)
x = u/(u+v)
hist(x, prob=T, br=50)
```

[image]

You can derive the PDF of $X = \frac{u}{U+V}$ by using
a bivariate transformation.

Comment: Does this approach also work if U and V and not independent?